# Navigation View is not calling onNavigationItemSelected method

Tags: android, navigationview

I'm using a NavigationView in a DrawerLayout, I'm not sure if I've forgotten something, but just is hidding the Navigation when I click it.

this is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
  private void instantiateDrawerLayout() {
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) generalContent.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorMainActivity));
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorMainActivity)));
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        Log.d("instantiateDrawerLayout", "called");
        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
        ...
    }

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Log.d("onNavigationItem", "called");
    final int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
    Intent intent;
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.navigation_item_1:
            hideDrawer();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_2:
            intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_3:
            intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_4:
            intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

activity_general.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

menu_drawer.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!--All the items added without any grouping-->

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_1"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_2"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_2" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_3"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_3" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_number_4"
        android:title="@string/navigation_item_4" />

</menu>
```

and my Logcat:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ydyz.png)

Comment: why do you use `System.gc()` everytime?

Comment: I'm a begginer, I try to clean the memory always I start or end and Activity.

Comment: it is not necessary, just `finish()` and system will do all itself

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot erase that part, in first time the MainActivity was not closed, for that I don't call finish(). But I forgot erase, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, was for the orden in the Layout.

As you see I put the NavigationView first, and It causes when I clicked over the NavigationView thinks I clicked In LinearLayout, or I think this this is what is happened.

Just change the order and all fine.